# Why i get dead code warnig if there is a break in the for loop?

Tags: java, dead-code

```
public static void harcos1csapatbaHelyez()
{
    for (int i=0 ; i<7 ; i++)
    {
        if (ElsoJatekos.elsoJatekosCsapata[i] == 0)
        {
            ElsoJatekos.elsoJatekosCsapata[i] = 1;

            break;  //If i dont remove it, it will cause a dead code warning and the for loop will be execute just once! How can I jump out from this loop otherwise?
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Elérted a maximális csapatlétszámot!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the complete loop? the warning is probably related to the rest of the code after the break

Comment: Why are you breaking in both if and else clauses? This means your loop will only have a single iteration, so why have a loop?

Comment: you do realise that the loop will execute exactly once? you're breaking out of it in the two if branches

Comment: Why do you use a loop if the only index you check is `0`? Either remove the `break` in the `else` block or the remove the whole loop and keep the `if/else`.

Comment: Can you added the definition of `ElsoJatekos.elsoJatekosCsapata` to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that you have a `break`, but that you have *two* of them. Both of the `break`s are located in opposite branches of a conditional `if` statement, which amounts to an unconditional `break`. No matter what side of the `if` your code takes, there's a `break` at the end.

This means that the `i++` statement from the loop header will never get executed; that is your dead code.

Comment: Oh my god you saved my life, yeah the second break was unnecessary, thanks a lot and sorry for being a noob :D

Comment: @FrigyesVass No reason to be sorry, this is not an obvious thing at all. Java compiler uses a lot of analysis to figure it out. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 2):

Because `i++` is never executed. `break` inside a loop means "leave the loop immediately." **Both** branches of your `if`/`else` have it, so *both* break out of the loop on the first iteration, and the `i++` part of the `for` never gets a chance to run. The `for` loop may as well be simply `int i = 0;` followed by the code currently in the loop body (without `break;`s), if you don't intend to loop.

Presumably, you're looping for a reason, and at most only *one* of those blocks should have the `break`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete but I can still identify where is the issue at...
you have this for loop and inside of it an **if-else**...

if you look carefully there is something peculiar in that if else:

**if the condition is met you break the loop but if the condition is not met you break the loop too...**

that means no matter if this is true or not `ElsoJatekos.elsoJatekosCsapata[i] == 0` you will break the loop and **ALL** that is written after the if-else becomes dead-code...

you will never executed... the IDE is smart enough to figure out that...

that is the reason why the IDE is complaining....

```
public static void harcos1csapatbaHelyez()
        {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if (ElsoJatekos.elsoJatekosCsapata[i] == 0) {
                ElsoJatekos.elsoJatekosCsapata[i] = 1;
                break;  
            } else {
                System.out.println("Elérted a maximális csapatlétszámot!");
                break;
            }

        //
        // something else here that is dead-code
        }
```

}